Does {128 - 32{1'b0} } mean 96'b0?
I am using PHY using GTH example Verilog code.
In the example code, there is an assign statement.
{128-P_TX_USER_DATA_WIDTH{1'b0}}

If P_TX_USER_DATA_WIDTH = 32, the above code becomes {128 - 32{1'b0}}.
Does it mean 96'b0?

Always start with simulation.
module tb;
    parameter P_TX_USER_DATA_WIDTH = 32;
    initial begin
        $display({128-P_TX_USER_DATA_WIDTH{1'b0}});
        $display($bits({128-P_TX_USER_DATA_WIDTH{1'b0}}));
    end
endmodule

Output:
                        0
     96

This demonstrates that the expression evaluates to 0.
It also shows, in this context, there are 96 bits of 0.
You could add parentheses to make the expression clearer:
{(128-P_TX_USER_DATA_WIDTH){1'b0}}

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2023, Table 11-2—Operator precedence and associativity.  Concatenation has the lowest precedence.

A better way to code this would be
assign foo = '0;
This effectively means "all zeros" and removes the need to use parameters at all.
